# Visual Studio 2015 Class Diagram Relationships

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, class-diagram, relationships

Is there any way I can add the types of relationships between classes in Visual Studio ? I already found out how to deal with associations, but now I need to deal with Dependency and Aggregation/Composition,I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community, thank you !